# CKEditor - How to hide Browse Server button in specific required places?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I use CKEditor in my application that in turn helps the user to create an article sort of stuff. (I basically use Jquery and JavaScript)
In many places like Flash Properties, Image Properties and Link of CKEditor tools, there's something called BrowseServer. I want to disable or hide this button only in 2 places say Flash Props and Image Props, and strictly not in other areas.
Can someone help me how do I accomplish that?
@anant dabhi
Ref : This is how I do it in JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['articleDesc'];
        if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'articleDesc',
            {
                fullPage : false,
                extraPlugins : 'docprops',
                filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/browse/BrowseServlet',
                filebrowserUploadUrl : '/upload/UploadServletForCKEditor',
                filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '/browse/BrowseServlet',
                filebrowserImageUploadUrl : '/upload/UploadServletForCKEditor',
                filebrowserWindowWidth  : 800,
                filebrowserWindowHeight : 500
            });
        CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function() {
            var headTxt = $(".cke_dialog_title").text();
            console.log("Browe Type : "+headTxt);
            if( headTxt == "Flash Properties" || headTxt == "Image Properties") {
                $(".cke_dialog_title").parent().find(".cke_dialog_ui_button").hide();
            }
        } );

    //]]>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove button using "`removeButtons`"
here is a js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['articleDesc'];
        if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'articleDesc',
            {
                fullPage : false,
                extraPlugins : 'docprops',
                filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/browse/BrowseServlet',
                filebrowserUploadUrl : '/upload/UploadServletForCKEditor',
                filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '/browse/BrowseServlet',
                filebrowserImageUploadUrl : '/upload/UploadServletForCKEditor',
                filebrowserWindowWidth  : 800,
                filebrowserWindowHeight : 500
            });
        CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function() {
            var headTxt = $(".cke_dialog_title").text();
            console.log("Browe Type : "+headTxt);
            if( headTxt == "Flash Properties" || headTxt == "Image Properties") {
                $(".cke_dialog_title").parent().find(".cke_dialog_ui_button").hide();
            }
        } );
//here u remove button code
 CKEDITOR.config.removeButtons = 'BrowseServer';
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: this may remove the button from all the places, but I want it to be removed in specific places only. And BTW, where should I keep the line you have said.
For reference, here's how I'm initiating CKEditor in a JS file..
<code>
//<![CDATA[
 var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['contactInfo'];
 if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'contactInfo',
  {
   // necessities...
  });
 //]]>
</code>

Comment: where u  intilize your CKeditor ? can u write ur code in qustion ?